# 404 page not found codeigniter version 2.1.4 running on hostgator

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My site has been running for years and I used codeigniter framework version 2.1.4. Until yesterday everything was OK.

But early this morning i started getting this error

> **404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.**.

What might be the problem? Capitalizing first letter of the controller files and class names hasn't helped

Comment: Check whether apache `Mod_rewrite` is still enabled and its working. Check with hosting provider also. There is a chance for this error due to server side update too.

Comment: Post `.htaccess` file code.

Comment: check the version of the PHP

Answer (score 0):

to get more information about your errors use following in `index.php` file in project root directory

```
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

now post your error description here to get the solution

(you will find this code block in `switch (ENVIRONMENT)`)